# Variable width tabs (auto width)

Tags: css, tabs, variable-width

I am trying to create tabs using CSS instead of images. I want the tabs to automatically adjust to the content within them, however I want them to have a max-width of 200px. I would like for the tab width to adjust to the content automatically so that the tabs will have variable widths but maintain the 20px left/right padding. Can anyone explain how to go about this?

Here's my HTML so far:

```
<div class="tab">
TEST
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.tab {
    text-align:center;
    background:#000;
    padding:0 20px;
    max-width:200px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    color:#fff;
}
```

[And a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heXSj/)!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `display:inline` css or make the div a span:

```
<span class="tab">
TEST
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing display:table-cell because I want to vertically align the text, but display:inline also worked. Will accept this answer in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

add **display: inline-block** to make it collapse to the width of the content.